# Why I got this error when trying to insert into table? sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: owners

Tags: python, sqlite, kivy

I have a Kivy app and I created a database in build function this is my database

```
 con = sqlite3.connect("my_db.db")
        c = con.cursor()
        c.execute("""CREATE TABLE if not exists owners(
        name TEXT,
        OwnerId INT,
        gender TEXT,
        email TEXT,
        password TEXT,
        image BLOB
        )""")
        con.commit()
        con.close()
```

and here my insertion function

```
def add_owner(self, obj):
        con = sqlite3.connect("my_db.db")
        c = con.cursor()
        #don't forget the image
        data = (self.owner_name.text,self.owner_id.text,self.owner_gender.text,self.owner_email.text,self.owner_password.text,b)
        c.execute("""INSERT INTO owners(name,OwnerId,gender,email,password, image) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""",data)
        con.commit()
        con.close()
```

it works perfectly if I didn't add the image but when I try to add it I got this problem

`sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: owners`

I tried deleting the database and 'tableName' and tried other things here in Stackoverflow but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Drop the table and rerun.

Comment: You're working with a relative path to the file here. Maybe the working directory changed between the two calls and you access an existing but different data file.

Comment: I tried Dropping it but nothing happened. Can't I solve the problem? I just don't know why it's only happens if I tried to add image.

Comment: You didn't rerun the `CREATE TABLE` code after dropping the table.

Comment: I did but nothing changed. Not only this table I have another 2 tables and I still have the same problem.